# Something like boilerpipe for python3

Tags: html, python-3.x, boilerpipe

I need a general tool, to extract a content from HTML documents. For python2 the boilerpipe is usually recommended.

Is there any similar alternative for python3?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [jusText](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jusText/2.1.0)

```
pip install justext
```

Below are some alternatives:

- http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/webascorpus/?source=navbar
- https://github.com/jiminoc/goose
- https://github.com/grangier/python-goose
- https://github.com/miso-belica/readability.py
- https://github.com/dcramer/decruft
- https://github.com/FeiSun/ContentExtraction
- https://github.com/JalfResi/justext
- https://github.com/andreypopp/extracty/tree/master/justext
- https://github.com/dreamindustries/jaws/tree/master/justext
- https://github.com/says/justext https://github.com/chbrown/justext
- https://github.com/says/justext-app

Answer (score 0):

Boilerpipe for python 3

```
pip install boilerpipe-py3
```